# Multi-tenant applications in Rails 3 with DB separation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant

How to correctly change database configuration for multi-tenant app in Rails 3?

At this point, I'm switching DB configuration in ApplicationController's before filter, like following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_database

  def set_database
    db_name = get_db_name

    spec = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
    new_spec = spec.clone
    new_spec["database"] = db_name
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(new_spec)
  end
end
```

Is this a good way? I have a concerns regarding user sessions. How can I correctly change session store settings, e.g. `:key`? Another problem here is, if user session is stored in DB, because it seems that user session is loaded in rack middleware before ApplicationController code.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between databases, this [solution](http://bit.ly/lo53Ys) looks cleaner. Update the `conn` method will the logic of your `get_db_name` method. Hope this helps.